# 113/tcp close ident report when i do port scan a website

Tags: networking

I am not able to view some website
i receive     113/tcp  close ident ,  3389/tcp  closed  ms-wbt-server

report when i do port scan for some websites 
i think my all my TCP service is disabled is there any way to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

3389, tcp, rdp, Port is IANA registered for Microsoft WBT Server, used for Windows Remote Desktop and Remote Assistance connections.

So unless you use Windows Remote Desktop and Remote Assistance connections, you won't be able to use it.

See [Ubuntu Networking Configuration Using Command Line](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-networking-configuration-using-command-line.html).